# how to check if is_active or not in symfony 1.2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have an array of object having following data in there as :

```
  object(EvaluationRemedy)#166 (26) {
  ["id":protected]=>
  int(9)
  ["title":protected]=>
  string(24) "Wheat Grass Juice Powder"
  ["description":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["diet":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["is_local_food_store":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["product_img":protected]=>
  string(44) "648d05d2731367752c93b2cdc96cca7fd7fba945.png"
  ["product_desc":protected]=>
  string(436) "This is an Organic Wheat Grass JUICE Powder, not just a Wheat Grass Powder - Grown on Ancient Sea Beds Enhancing Trace Mineral Absorption - Non-GMO and No gluten. Contains the equivalent of 92 minerals, 20 amino acids and plenty of nutrients, including B12. One teaspoon is equivalent to 14 shots of 100% pure organic wheat grass juice. This is a very concentrated nutrient. No more hassle with cleaning your juicer, just mix and drink."
  ["product_url":protected]=>
  string(60) "https://shop.drberg.com/raw-wheat-grass-juice-powder-regular"
  ["importance":protected]=>
  int(10)
  ["is_active":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["created_at":protected]=>
  string(19) "2014-11-07 21:41:54"
  ["updated_at":protected]=>
  string(19) "2016-12-21 10:28:55"
  ["collEvaluationRemedyRelatedsRelatedByEvaluationRemedyId":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["lastEvaluationRemedyRelatedRelatedByEvaluationRemedyIdCriteria":"BaseEvaluationRemedy":private]=>
  NULL
  ["collEvaluationRemedyRelatedsRelatedByEvaluationRelRemedyId":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["lastEvaluationRemedyRelatedRelatedByEvaluationRelRemedyIdCriteria":"BaseEvaluationRemedy":private]=>
  NULL
  ["collEvaluationCauseRemedys":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["lastEvaluationCauseRemedyCriteria":"BaseEvaluationRemedy":private]=>
  NULL
  ["collEvaluationSymptomRemedys":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["lastEvaluationSymptomRemedyCriteria":"BaseEvaluationRemedy":private]=>
  NULL
  ["alreadyInSave":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["alreadyInValidation":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["validationFailures":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_new":"BaseObject":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_deleted":"BaseObject":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["modifiedColumns":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

It's saved as in following variable as :

```
<?php $productDetails = EvaluationRemedyAdminPeer::getProductInfo($remedyId);  ?>
```

I want to show only active records so how can I call that?

I checked with these but none of these worked as :

```
<?php if ($productDetails->isActive()) { echo "YES"; } else { echo "NO"; } ?>
<?php if ($productDetails->is_active()) { echo "YES"; } else { echo "NO"; } ?>
<?php if ($productDetails->getIsActive()) { echo "YES"; } else { echo "NO"; } ?>
<?php if ($productDetails->checkisActive()) { echo "YES"; } else { echo "NO"; } ?>
```

So how can I check for it then?

**NOTE : Symfony Version is 1.2.12**

Answer (score 1):

On any given PHP object you can always list all the available methods using

```
var_dump ( get_class_methods( $object ) );
```

Reference on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php)

That said, for your specific case, I would just open the file containing the class `EvaluationRemedy` and look at the methods available there.

Or even rather invest in a correct IDE helping you with proper code completion.

Comment: Can you remove your answer so that I can remove this question please?